# Rails 3 Tutorial Chapter 11 HTML not showing for Follow/Unfollow button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

Here is my show.html.erb file.

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= gravatar_for @user %>
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section>
            <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_follow.html.erb partial file:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id),
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

_unfollow.html.erb partial file:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user),
             html: { method: :delete },
             remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

And my _follow_form.html.erb partial:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit: I would also like to say that I'm using Bootstrap. When I inspect the user page, both classes span4 and span8 come up, but there is a complete blank where "follow_form" should be.

Edit: This question was answered years ago :)

Comment: Are you sure you're signed in? Have you tried removing the `if signed_in?` from your show.html.erb?

Comment: Hartl has you write tests before writing code.  Do your tests pass?

Comment: Also, if you're still doing the Rails Tutorial (and assuming you're still looking at this question), then you're likely checking your code in to Github, so would you like to give out a link to your repo so people can run your tests for themselves?

Answer (score 0):

i came across the same problem , you can rectify this by doing the following changes :

step 1) 
In app/views/users/show.html.erb
change code from this :

```
<div class = "span8">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>      
        <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
```

to this:

```
<div class = "span8">
    <%= render 'shared/follow_form' if signed_in? %>      
        <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
```

step 2) 
In partial  app/views/shared/_follow_form.html.erb

change the code from this :

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <%if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

to this :

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <%if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'shared/unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'shared/follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If the partials are not in the shared directory but only in the users directory, than this will make the app crash. I'm actually having the same problem and have yet to figure out why it is happening.